# Firebug use with fullscreen API

Tags: html, firebug, fullscreen

I'm using on a website the fullscreen feature offered by HTML5. With chrome I can modify the style with webkit developer —in fullscreen mode— just fine.

But when I'm using Firefox with Firebug, I can't, because when I clink on the firebug panel (on a separate window on another monitor — I have a dual monitor setup) the page exits fullscreen mode.

How can I resolve this?

**Edit**, additional info:

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.2, Firefox 21 with Firebug 1.11.4

I've tested this on Windows 7, Firefox 21 and the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here: [Html5 video won't stay full screen on second monitor?](https://support.mozilla.org/it/questions/927294)

In brief, set `full-screen-api.exit-on-deactivate` to `false` in `about:config`. It's a configuration setting available since Firefox 13.

For anyone interested, the bug is explained here: [Bug 724554 - Don't exit fullscreen when focusing window on different display](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=724554).